# glDrawArrays unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, opengl

I have spent a good amount of time with the fixed pipeline of openGL, and I have recently began learning the programmable pipeline. I know my painter, and shader classes are not the issue because they work with fixed function pipeline stuff. I can't seem to get glDrawArrays to work for my life.

I am not sure if my error is in how i set up the vertex buffer object, in my shader or else where. I have debugged my code also and set breakpoints throughout the display function, and it seems to never get past glDrawArrays(), (i.e. it hits a breakpoint at glDrawArrays, but doesn't hit any after, not sure why.)

What gets outputted is just a white screen, nothing else.

Heres my code:

```
float   vertices[] = {   0.75,  0.75, 0.0, 1.0,
                         0.75, -0.75, 0.0, 1.0,
                        -0.75, -0.75, 0.0, 1.0 };

GLuint  vertexBufferObject;
GLuint  positionLocation;
GLuint  vaoObject;

void initVertexBuffer(GLuint& vertexBufferObject, float* vertexData, unsigned int size, GLenum GL_DRAW_TYPE)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, vertexData, GL_DRAW_TYPE);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    painter.initEngine(argc, argv, 500, 500, 0, 0, "2D3D");
    painter.initGlutFuncs(display, resize, Input::MouseButtonClick,   Input::MouseDrag, keyboard);

    defaultShader.init("default.vert", "default.frag"); 
    defaultShader.link();

    initVertexBuffer(vertexBufferObject, vertices, sizeof(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoObject);
    positionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(defaultShader.id(), "position");

    painter.startMainLoop();
}

void display()
{
    painter.clearDisplay();

    defaultShader.bind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    std::cout << Framework::glErrorCheck() << std::endl;

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    defaultShader.unbind();

    painter.flushAndSwapBuffers();
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 140

in vec4 position; 

void main()
{   
    gl_Position = position; 
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 140

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Edit:** Code updated with Joey Dewd, keltar, and genpfault's suggestions.
      I'm no longer hanging at glDrawArrays, i.e. instead of a white screen I'm getting a black screen. This is leading me to think that my buffer is somehow still not setup correctly. Or possibly, I am missing something else needed for the vertex array buffer initialization (vaoObject)?

Comment: I think your issue is that you are not using Vertex Attribute Arrays in your drawing commands. If I'm recalling correctly the programmable pipeline requires a VAO setup before using calls like `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`.

Comment: @JoeyDewd Thanks, this fixed my program hanging on glDrawArrays, but still no triangle action going on.

Comment: @hdavehb: You're almost there I believe, currently you got the order wrong. The order should be as follows: `1. Bind VAO object. 2. Bind buffer and setup its data and the VertexAttribPointers.`. The VAO Stores all the buffer commands you did while binding to its VAO. This means, that once you bound the VAO any subsequent VBO/EBO and pointer calls will be stored so the next time you need to draw, you only need to call `glBindVertexArray(VAO)`. Try binding the VAO first, then the subsequent buffer and attribPointer calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void initVertexBuffer(GLuint vertexBufferObject, float* vertexData, GLenum GL_DRAW_TYPE)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_DRAW_TYPE);
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ nnnnope
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

[`sizeof(vertexData)` in this context is not what you seem to hope it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349610/44729).

It'll probably be 4 or 8 depending on your 64-bit-edness.  I.e., the `sizeof` a pointer-to-float.  *Not* `sizeof(vertices)`.

You need to pass in a separate size argument:

```
void initVertexBuffer(GLuint& vertexBufferObject, float* vertexData, unsigned int size, GLenum GL_DRAW_TYPE)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, vertexData, GL_DRAW_TYPE);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

...

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...
    initVertexBuffer(vertexBufferObject, vertices, sizeof(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ...    
}
```

Or a contiguous (important!) standard container like `std::vector`:

```
template< typename Container >
void initVertexBuffer(GLuint& vertexBufferObject, const Container& vertexData, GLenum GL_DRAW_TYPE)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData.size() * sizeof( typename Container::value_type ), &vertexData[0], GL_DRAW_TYPE);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

---

Full example:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
        if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
        if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader


void initVertexBuffer(GLuint& vertexBufferObject, float* vertexData, unsigned int size, GLenum GL_DRAW_TYPE)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, vertexData, GL_DRAW_TYPE);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

GLuint prog;
GLuint vaoObject;
void init()
{
    const char* vert = GLSL
    (
        140,
        in vec4 position; 
        void main()
        {   
            gl_Position = position; 
        }
    );

    const char* frag = GLSL
    (
        140,
        out vec4 outColor;
        void main()
        {
            outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    );

    prog = Program::Load( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram( prog );

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoObject);

    float vertices[] = 
    {   
        0.75,  0.75, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.75, -0.75, 0.0, 1.0,
        -0.75, -0.75, 0.0, 1.0 
    };
    GLuint vertexBufferObject;
    initVertexBuffer(vertexBufferObject, vertices, sizeof(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);

    GLuint positionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram( prog );
    glBindVertexArray(vaoObject);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitContextVersion( 3, 1 );
    glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, and good catch, i totally would've overlooked this. although it did not fix my issue unfortunately.

Comment: @hbdavehb: As keltar pointed out you'll need to pass `vertexBufferObject` by-reference instead of by-value.  Edited to add the necessary ampersands.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate you writing up a whole example, it along with @JoeyDewd's advice helped me realize the order of binding/initialing my buffers/vertexarryobject was messed up. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome!  In the future I'd recommend leading off with a complete program like that (feel free to reuse it!) since the statefulness of OpenGL can make it difficult to figure out exactly what's going on with just snippets of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
```

Saves id of vertex buffer in local variable. This value no longer available in draw call and does *not* modify global `vertexBufferObject` (yet buffer still exists - you just lost its id and can't use it anymore. can't even destroy it)